# Does the angular $interval cancel itself after exceeding 'count' parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intervals

Quick question about the $interval service in angular.  Looking at the docs ([$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)) they warn you to manually cancel intervals, but you have the option of providing a count parameter upon initialization.  Once the timer has "ticked" past the allotted count does it cancel itself or simply stop calling the function and live on in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR; After the count, the interval is cleared.

As the same documentation says, it is recommended that you cancel the $interval when the scope of your controller is detroyed. Something like:

```
var t = $interval(function(){
    ...
}, 1000);


$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    $interval.cancel(t);
});
```

The delay parameter is time interval which the function is called. In the example above, the function is called every 1000 milliseconds. If you don't cancel the $interval, Angular will hold a reference to it, and may continue to execute your function, causing strange behaviors in your app.

Considering that the $interval provider is just a wrapper of the native setInterval(), with the adition of the $apply, looking at the Angular implementation (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/interval.js), we can find this snippet of code:

```
if (count > 0 && iteration >= count) {
  deferred.resolve(iteration);
  clearInterval(promise.$$intervalId);
  delete intervals[promise.$$intervalId];
}
```

So, the promise created by the provider is resolved, and the interval is cleared. The cancel method does this:

```
intervals[promise.$$intervalId].reject('canceled');
$window.clearInterval(promise.$$intervalId);
delete intervals[promise.$$intervalId];
```

So, I think your assumption is right. After the count, the interval is already cleared.

Comment: Thanks for this digging in the source code. Too bad this isn't mentioned in the docs.