# Cancel $interval when execution count is set?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval

When I start an `$interval` like this:

```
$interval(() => {
  console.log("interval executed");
}, 0, 1);
```

it will be executed one time (because of the set execution count parameter).

**My question**
Do I still have to call `$interval.cancel(intervalPromise)` (regarding to memory), or is this not necessary?

The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) say

> A promise which will be notified on each iteration. It will resolve once all iterations of the interval complete.

which makes me suspect, that a call to `cancel` might not be necessary, but I am not 100% sure about how intervals in AngularJs are affecting memory like *VanillaJs* intervals do. (What I mean: as long as an interval is not cleared in *VanillaJs* the garbage collector can obviously **not** collect the interval handler)

Comment: If you are worried about performance then you should test your hypothesis. Start with no timers and then try 100 then 10k then 1M and check the memory usage. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scipper, I too had similar doubts few months ago after which I came across a similar question here on SO.

As per the accepted answer, the interval is cleared after the execution happens after the specified number of times. The guy who has answered doesn't seem to be that sure, but that is the only arguably good reasoning out that I've found after a lot of searching the web.

Here is the [SO article on the similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31363551/10232790) -- [Does the angular $interval cancel itself after exceeding 'count' parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363430/does-the-angular-interval-cancel-itself-after-exceeding-count-parameter)

Comment: Oh, I didn't find that one. It's a bit old, but the link to AngularJs sources made things clear to me: after the count is reached, angular calls the clearInterval function. Thanks!

Comment: Glad if it helped...